# How do I call an intent from a class that is already calling an intent?

Tags: android

I want to receive the intent being called in the foodimg part in the addit part. But idk how to call an intent from a class that's already called it.

I tried typing the code in the addit as well and everything is in red. How would the code look like if I wanted to call the intent again? and send it to another class?

````
 ```int foodImg = getIntent().getIntExtra("Image", 0);
    mainImg.setImageResource(foodImg);
    name1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title"));
    name2.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Price"));


    addit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            name3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String cv = name3.getText().toString();
            int val = Integer.parseInt(cv);
            val++;
            name3.setText(String.valueOf(val));

            if(val>=5){
                addit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else if(val>=0){
                minuss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    });```
````

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding correctly, you would like to use ```getIntent()``` inside ```OnClickListener``` of ```addit```? How do you add it?

Comment: I wanna send data from the addit button to another class. But the class addit is in is already receiving an Intent. So I wanna get that intent and again send the same details to another class

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to bring your data further to another `Activity`, you have the following approach:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Do onCreate() stuff here
    // ...

    // Extract your previous data into Bundle first
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    Button addit = findViewById(R.id.btnAddIt);
    addit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your necessary work here
            // ...
            // Create new Intent to your next Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            // Put your data in form of Bundle in this new Intent
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            // Start your next Activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

And again you can use `getIntent().getExtras()` to get your necessary data out in next `Activity`.